# Heroku deployment through docker image - Home page not showing up

Tags: java, docker, heroku, web-applications

I deployed a docker image using the steps provided on  heroku site. 
App was successfully create; images got created and pushed. Got the url for the app as well but i don't see my home page. It shows me the page pulled by url below:
https://funapp08.herokuapp.com

This is not what i was expecting.
When i checked the logs; heroku seem to have started the app (it is an excutable war packaged as jar, suppose to run on 8080 with context root of funApp) - pls check the logs below - but it does not seem to be hitting the app.

On local docker setup it runs fine with url : :8080/funApp

Why am i not able to access it on heroku? 
Below is the docker file:

FROM abhi/java8img

WORKDIR /app

ADD funApp.jar /app/funApp.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD /usr/bin/java -jar funApp.jar

I also tried appending the contextRoot to the heroku url. But it did not helped.
Pls throw some light on it.

Thanks in Adv
Abhi

```
19-01-11T07:13:40.834007+00:00 heroku[run.3783]: Process exited with status 127
2019-01-11T07:14:44.081599+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (6a68f06d9ea0), release (6a68f06d9ea0) by user abhi.whiling@gmail.com
2019-01-11T07:15:07.628868+00:00 heroku[release.5044]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c 'if curl https://heroku-release-output.s3.amazonaws.com/log-stream?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ3LIQ2SWG7V76SVQ%2F20190111%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190111T071504Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=9c084980d1293f282c0bb704c763eaa7d885c7e0ead0d490ca4f3d620e58643c --silent --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 >/tmp/log-stream; then   chmod u+x /tmp/log-stream   /tmp/log-stream /bin/sh -c '"'"'/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/java\ -jar\ funApp.jar'"'"' else   /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/java\ -jar\ funApp.jar fi'`
2019-01-11T07:15:10.076849+00:00 app[release.5044]: /bin/sh: curl: not found
2019-01-11T07:15:12.594518+00:00 app[release.5044]: Jan 11, 2019 7:15:12 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol init
2019-01-11T07:15:12.594543+00:00 app[release.5044]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2019-01-11T07:15:12.646077+00:00 app[release.5044]: Jan 11, 2019 7:15:12 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
2019-01-11T07:15:12.646081+00:00 app[release.5044]: INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2019-01-11T07:15:12.662325+00:00 app[release.5044]: Jan 11, 2019 7:15:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2019-01-11T07:15:12.662328+00:00 app[release.5044]: INFO: Starting service Tomcat
2019-01-11T07:15:12.663415+00:00 app[release.5044]: Jan 11, 2019 7:15:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2019-01-11T07:15:12.663417+00:00 app[release.5044]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
2019-01-11T07:15:17.441905+00:00 app[release.5044]: Jan 11, 2019 7:15:17 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol start
2019-01-11T07:15:17.441925+00:00 app[release.5044]: INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2019-01-11T07:21:17.107571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=funapp08.herokuapp.com request_id=cf30a472-f94f-48e1-ae39-670ff3e6a7eb fwd="171.76.213.1" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-11T07:21:17.513276+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=funapp08.herokuapp.com request_id=c486848b-7868-4ad1-95e1-f9c7f1397967 fwd="171.76.213.1" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-11T07:47:12.584156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=funapp08.herokuapp.com request_id=eb8a19af-c6d2-4171-9d0e-0db767a0b0ec fwd="171.76.213.1" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-11T07:47:12.974387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=funapp08.herokuapp.com request_id=41c79168-b385-4c63-8d36-bcc298a6ae0d fwd="171.76.213.1" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-11T07:47:54.055642+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=funapp08.herokuapp.com request_id=9289a3c1-3ade-4386-aa96-554d5b859a48 fwd="171.76.213.1" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-11T07:47:54.429267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=funapp08.herokuapp.com request_id=972acced-6e9e-4b1e-9d4f-0d9bd11a5b96 fwd="171.76.213.1" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
docker@default:/c/Users/Abhi/DockerAppHub/heroku/bin$ ping funapp08.herokuapp.com
PING funapp08.herokuapp.com (54.208.247.255): 56 data bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't support `EXPOSE`. You'll need your app to bind to the port defined by the `PORT` env var (which is set for you).

Comment: Ya, was able to deploy the container using webApp-runner. Though i wanted a single jar with embedded app server but i guess the option to set port at runtime is not their. Have to shift to war package to achieve the results. –